# Random images with no repeat php

Tags: database, image, cookies, random, unique

I have my pictures stored in server file named images, there is like over 300 of them. In the database I have this pictures assigned to ID's.

In database is like

```
ID: 300
photoPath: "images/300.png"
```

And now I need to show them in a website by **random without repeat each after refresh**. I generate them by random in php

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); // I get that one image's ID and path
```

Now I somehow need to make sure, that non of the images after refresh repeats. I think I should write ID of the image to cookies and later just check if picture with this ID was shown before. But how should I do it? Should I create array of ID's in one cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three general solutions to the non-duplicate random number problem:

- If you want a few numbers from a large range then pick one and reject it if it is a duplicate. If the range is large, then this won't cause too many repeated attempts.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a small range, then set out all the numbers in an array and shuffle the array. The Fisher-Yates algorithm is standard for array shuffling. Take the random numbers in sequence from the shuffled array.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a large range then use an appropriately sized encryption algorithm. E.g. for 64 bit numbers use DES and encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... in sequence. The output is guaranteed unique because encryption is reversible. The Hasty Pudding Cipher can be set for any convenient range of numbers.